# Faster pyomo constraint formulation

Tags: pyomo

I have a `ConcreteModel` and a totally vectorized pyomo `ConstraintList` that works very well. Although IPOPT solves it in ~8 sec, but evaluation of the model takes ~40 sec. Here are the report_timing output as well as the constraints snippet:

```
[+   0.20] Processed 1 objectives
[+   0.20] Processed 1 objectives
[+   0.20] Processed 1 objectives
[+   0.20] Processed 1 objectives
[+  23.26] Processed 12410 constraints
[+  23.26] Processed 12410 constraints
[+  23.26] Processed 12410 constraints
[+  23.26] Processed 12410 constraints
[   24.22] Generated NL representation
[   24.22] Generated NL representation
[   24.22] Generated NL representation
[   24.22] Generated NL representation
24.29 seconds required to write file
24.29 seconds required for presolve
```

```py
# Define the constraints
pmo.constraints = pyo.ConstraintList()

for i in pmo.i:
    force = list()
    for mi in pmo.mi:
        # (#1) geometry constraint
        pmo.constraints.add( pmo.MLAT[i,mi]**2 + pmo.height[mi]**2 == (pmo.NML[i,mi]*pmo.MLopt[mi])**2 )

        # (#2) length velocity constraint
        if i == 0:     # second order forward difference
            _NMLDot = ((-3*pmo.NML[i,mi]+4*pmo.NML[i+1,mi]-pmo.NML[i+2,mi])/2/iDt)
        elif i == 1:    # first order forward difference
            _NMLDot = ((pmo.NML[i+1,mi]-pmo.NML[i,mi])/1/iDt)
        elif i == iN-2:  # first order backward difference
            _NMLDot = ((pmo.NML[i,mi]-pmo.NML[i-1,mi])/1/iDt)
        elif i == iN-1:  # second order backward difference
            _NMLDot = ((3*pmo.NML[i,mi]-4*pmo.NML[i-1,mi]+pmo.NML[i-2,mi])/2/iDt)
        else:           # central difference
            _NMLDot = ((pmo.NML[i+1,mi]-pmo.NML[i-1,mi])/2/iDt)
        pmo.constraints.add( _NMLDot / pmo.CVmax[mi] == pmo.NMV[i,mi])

        # (#3) force equilibrium [external function]
        TF, MFAT = utils.calcForcePyomo(
                pmo.act[i,mi], pmo.NML[i,mi], pmo.NMV[i,mi], pmo.MLAT[i,mi], \
                pmo.MTL[i,mi], pmo.IFmax[mi], pmo.MLopt[mi], pmo.TLslk[mi] )
        pmo.constraints.add( TF == MFAT )
        force.append(MFAT)

    # (#4) moment equilibrium
    for cName in pmo.cName:
        _tau = iTauT.getDependentColumn(cName)[i] # float
        _moment = pyo.quicksum( iMomentArm[cName][i,mi] * force[mi] for mi in pmo.mi)
        pmo.constraints.add( _moment == _tau )
```

Any idea how to make it faster?

I also re-wrote the equivalent rule-based constraints but there were no improvements in computations time.

```py
def constraint_1(model, i, mi):
    return model.MLAT[i,mi]**2 + model.height[mi]**2 == (model.NML[i,mi]*model.MLopt[mi])**2

def constraint_2(model, i, mi):
    if i == 0:     # second order forward difference
        _NMLDot = ((-3*model.NML[i,mi]+4*model.NML[i+1,mi]-model.NML[i+2,mi])/2/iDt)
    elif i == 1:    # first order forward difference
        _NMLDot = ((model.NML[i+1,mi]-model.NML[i,mi])/1/iDt)
    elif i == iN-2:  # first order backward difference
        _NMLDot = ((model.NML[i,mi]-model.NML[i-1,mi])/1/iDt)
    elif i == iN-1:  # second order backward difference
        _NMLDot = ((3*model.NML[i,mi]-4*model.NML[i-1,mi]+model.NML[i-2,mi])/2/iDt)
    else:           # central difference
        _NMLDot = ((model.NML[i+1,mi]-model.NML[i-1,mi])/2/iDt)
    
    return (_NMLDot / model.CVmax[mi] == model.NMV[i,mi])

pmo.eq_1 = pyo.Constraint(pmo.i, pmo.mi, rule=constraint_1)
pmo.eq_2 = pyo.Constraint(pmo.i, pmo.mi, rule=constraint_2)


# store the output of the external function
pmo.TF, pmo.MFAT = {},{}

def buildForces(model, i, mi):
    model.TF[i,mi], model.MFAT[i,mi] = utils.calcForcePyomo(
            model.act[i,mi], model.NML[i,mi], model.NMV[i,mi], model.MLAT[i,mi], \
            model.MTL[i,mi], model.IFmax[mi], model.MLopt[mi], model.TLslk[mi] )

pmo.updForces = pyo.BuildAction(pmo.i, pmo.mi, rule=buildForces)


def constraint_3(model, i, mi):
    return model.TF[i,mi] == model.MFAT[i,mi]

def constraint_4(model, i, cName):
    _tau       = iTauT.getDependentColumn(cName)[i] # float
    moment     = pyo.quicksum( iMomentArm[cName][i,mi] * model.MFAT[i,mi] for mi in model.mi)
    return moment == _tau

pmo.eq_3 = pyo.Constraint(pmo.i, pmo.mi,    rule=constraint_3)
pmo.eq_4 = pyo.Constraint(pmo.i, pmo.cName, rule=constraint_4)
```

Sorry if there are too many scripts.
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's difficult to provide any meaningful help without a complete working example, but my first guess would be to convert `force` from a `list` to an named (and indexed) `Expression` object.  It would also (likely) be more efficient if you formulated the model as a series of indexed `Constraint`s with (simple) rules and not create the entire model as a single `ConstraintList`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I could solve the error of `BuildAction`, my bad; please see the newly edited post. Now both methods take ~40 sec, i.e., rule-based constraints are working the same as the big single `ConstraintList`. I'm afraid my entire case is too long. Any idea how to share the code and the associated data here? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: The easiest thing might be to either put the complete code in a public github repository, or to mail the code / question to the Pyomo Forum Google group (usually as a zip file - many email systems strip off python files).

Comment: Thanks again for your response. Please find the link to code and data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1og6ZKJOHWMf7bdbrjPiUyOu2OxfdUGfV/view?usp=sharing. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here is the code and data on GitHub: https://github.com/mrrezaie/testPYOMO. I would be grateful for your help. Thank you in advance.